# How do I setup the look & feel of Gnome applications while on KDE?

Tags: gnome, kde, themes

I guess the title is self descriptive. I just moved to KDE but the Gnome based apps (like  Banshee, Emacs, Tomboy and others) simply look terrible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pulled from: http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/gentoo/desktop/219652

On 10/15/2010 02:56 PM, Coert Waagmeester wrote:

> Hello all,
>
> How can I get a nice theme on firefox (and other gnome gtk apps) when I 
>   use KDE?
>
> I have installed the gtk qtcurve package.

Also install kde-misc/kcm_gtk. This will give you a new configuration 
option in System Settings (either in "Application Appearance" or in 
"Lost and Found" if you're on KDE 4.5.2) where you can configure Gtk.

In order to configure QtCurve itself though, you will also have to 
install x11-themes/qtcurve-qt4, and switch KDE from Oxygen to that, 
configure it (this also configures the Gtk version) and then switch back 
to Oxygen (the Gtk configuration of QtCurve will be kept.)

Comment: It worked, still many of my settings do not seem to survived a log out

Answer (score 1):

There is an oxygen gtk+ theme that will make gnome apps look consistent on Kubuntu. Its called funnily enough oxygen-gtk and you can download the deb installation file from kde-look

- [oxygen-gtk theme at kde-look](http://kde-look.org/content/show.php/Oxygen+Gtk?content=136216)

you need to download the "debian" file which is the third download option

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Install from the default repositories (using syaptics or command line "apt-get" or any tool you like):

- gtk3-engines-oxygen
- gtk2-engines-oxygen
  Then using "System settings" -> Application appearance -> gtk-appearance -> select an oxygen theme (and fonts, etc.)